# How can I import a .net standard class library into a .net framework project?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've created a class library targeted to .NetStandard 1.4, and packaged it as a nuget package.  So far so good, right?

I'm able to import it into my dotnet core 1.1 project, happy times.

However when I try to import it into my dotnet framework 4.5.2 project in VS 2017, I get an error, like so:

```
Could not install package 'YourClassLibrary 1.0.0'. You are trying to
install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I contacted the package author, but that's me, so *that* guy was no help.  I'd thought that this was a permissible operation.  What could I be doing wrong?

Update:  According to this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) my dotnet-standard 1.4 lib should work against up to dotnet-framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Post your update as an answer and accept it, or accept the other answer which indicates what's wrong.

Comment: Hmm ... I think my stackoverflow-fu is weak.  The update isn't an answer, it's another data point.  I did not see another answer saying what's wrong... I'd certainly love to see that!

Comment: you already know that .NET Standard 1.4 is only supported by .NET Framework 4.6.1 and above, and it won't work for .NET Framework 4.5.2. So why bother to ask when the answer is obvious.